# more command in windows cmd

Tags: bash, batch-file, window

We have `more` command in Windows and Linux. We have `-d` option with more for Linux but not for Windows. I want a similar functionality for Windows also. Please suggest.

- https://staff.washington.edu/corey/man/more
- http://ss64.com/bash/more.html

I get

```
more -d filename.txt: provide a message "Press space to continue, 'q' to quit."
```

when opening a file with `more` command.
I want to achieve same thing in Windows.

Comment: You can use `more /e` in windows, and then you can press q to quit, as seen [here](http://ss64.com/nt/more.html).

Comment: Type `more /?` into a command prompt window on Windows to find out what are all the supported options...

Answer (score 1):

more /e enables extended features

If extended features are enabled, the following commands
    are accepted at the -- More -- prompt:

```
P n     Display next n lines
S n     Skip next n lines
F       Display next file
Q       Quit
=       Show line number
?       Show help line
<space> Display next page
<ret>   Display next line
```

Comment: Yes /e will enable the extended feature. The main requirement is that I want to open a file page wise through a bash script , when the user will run the bash script then file will open page wise on cmd prompt but I want to show message at the end of prompt same as display in UNIX machine"Press space to continue, 'q' to quit."  Using more -d command. I want to display message because maye be user know or don't know how to quit or display next page in more command.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a similar message by typing '?' while o/p is being displayed.
it should display something similar like this

```
04/15/2016  07:58 AM    <DIR>          blah
10/07/2015  05:27 PM    <DIR>          blah-blah
-- More [Options: psfq=<space><ret>] --
```

Comment: Yes /e will enable the extended feature. The main requirement is that I want to open a file page wise through a bash script , when the user will run the bash script then file will open page wise on cmd prompt but I want to show message at the end of prompt same as display in UNIX machine"Press space to continue, 'q' to quit." Using more -d command. I want to display message because maye be user know or don't know how to quit or display next page in more command.